# Include customer feedback on my resume?

Tags: resume, feedback

I work in technical consulting on projects that include 1, maximum 2 people. At the end of each project, my firm sends the customer a feedback form with 5 simple questions - it is a KPI for the whole department and for single employees.

The result is a score between 1 and 10 plus a short positive comment, which are both usually very dependent on the lead consultant, due to the team size and type of work.

**Is this feedback something that could be included in a resume? How?**

The goal is to prove that clients are happy with my work, without sounding like a potential employer is reading an Amazon product review or a humorous dating profile.

I am currently not looking for a job, but I could not find similar questions on the site and could be useful for others.

*Edit based on comments*

Over one year I carry out and manage 10-15 projects; I would not include the single comments in my resume, but a one-liner in the description of this role (e.g. "90%+ customer appreciation over 20+ projects") just like I would write something along the lines of "Project manager for a total of $500k with a 30% margin"

Answer (score 6):

No no no

1. Think of the privacy of the individual. They filled in the form for a specific use. That use does not include your CV
2. The survey was done for the company. Its results and data belong to the company and not you
3. Would you employ somebody that does not care about personal data?

Comment: Good point about privacy, I do agree that the results belong to the company. But if I carry out multiple $100K projects with an average 30% margin, putting this type of KPI on my resume is encouraged. I would not include the personal comments because they are too dependent on the project (however they are good strength-weakness answers in an interview), but the overall average score is a number, like 90%, and is strongly dependent on my abilities as a team leader / project manager. I updated the question to be more specific, thank you for the input!

Answer (score 5):

I don't think individual comments would be appropriate but an overall score would good especially if it is high. One thing I know about these call centers is that at the end of the call, they give a survey. That survey is then used to measure your rating that is then used to rate you as a employee. A score of 98% is usually really, really good and I think that is a good thing to put on your resume. A 98% customer satisfaction score, as one of the bullet points.

Edit: It sounds like a star system is used. If your score is 4.8 out of 5, that is pretty good. Something like, "Rated 4.8 out of 5 in customer satisfaction."

Comment: That would be the general idea, yes, although I do not work in a call center :)
From an outside perspective, does it not sound like it is a product rating on Amazon?

Comment: Depends on how you present it. I think a simple bullet point that you were rated X out of Y and was ranked Z for the company callers.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an intro on your resume you could mention it there. Something along the lines of

> lauraapresa is a project manager experienced in carrying out projects over $100k with a 30% margin.... -something in between-
>   Over the past few years over 20 projects have been completed with a 90%+ customer satisfaction.